# More efficient than a Datatable

Tags: c#, performance

We have a reporting tool that is grabbing a large amount of records.  At times it can be 1 million records.   We have been storing this in a datable.  I wanted to to know if there was a better object to store this in.    I would need to be able to aggregate the data in various ways.

**Update:**
Yes. Personally believe that should not being getting that many records. This is not the direction I want to go.

Also I am using Oracle

**Update Update**

Sorry for the delay, but there are always fire to put out here.  The main issue was they were running out of memory and getting memory errors. They had issues with the datatable releasing from memory and also binding to a datagridview. I guess what I was looking for was a lighter weight object that wouldn't take as much space.

After thinking about a little more, it really doesn't make any sense to get that much data as diagonalbatman mentioned. furthermore if we have just a few people are using it with these issues.  How is it going to scale.

Unfortunately, I have a boss that doesn't listen and an offshore team that is too much of a "yes sir" type attitude.  They are serializing the raw data (as an XML file) and releasing the raw data Datatable which I think is not a good direction at all.

@diagonalbatman - OUt of curiousity, do you have an example of this

Comment: Have you performed any testing to determine where your bottlenecks actually are?

Comment: I'm not sure if this question is answerable in its current state.  Please provide a lot more detail.  Is the data related to other data you have stored?  etc etc

Comment: are you having an issue with the datatable?  what are you trying to overcome?  More details will help us help you better.

Comment: Make sure you're setting DataColumn.DataType ahead of time and filling it with compact binary objects and not string representations of integers for example.  Is the database on the same machine as the app?  What driver are you using?  (Getting large amounts of data out of a database is usually the slowest part)

Comment: You're not after something more efficient than a database. You're after a better understanding of how to use a database.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need to draw down 1 Milion records into your app?

Can you not do your reporting consolidation / aggregation on the DB? This would make better use of the DB's resources (after all this is what an RDBMS is designed to do) then you can focus your app on working with smaller consolidated sets?

Comment: I agree with that but the direction they want me to go is have the data available.

Comment: Thats fine, but can you not design the app to only "get" the data when you need it?

Comment: Yah.  Agree. It is ridiculous to think the user would need that much data.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you try several options to verify, especially in light of your needed ability to aggregate the data in various ways.

1) Can it be aggregated by proper queries on the data side, this is likely the best solution.

2) if you use POCOs does LINQ improve upon your current memory and performance characteristics.  Does LINQ allow you to to the aggregation you require.

Measure the characteristics you care about and try different options.

Answer (score 1):

What you want are Data Cubes.  Depending on the type of database you have, you should look at building some Cubes.